# Sweep time for Spectrum Analyzer

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

I have a basic question about sweep times and number of points.

- My frequency span of interest is: $f_{span} = 30\ \rm MHz$
- My resolution bandwidth is: $RBW = 10\ \rm kHz$
- The minimum number of points is: $n = 2\frac{f_{span}}{RBW} =  6000\ \rm points$
- My minimum dwell time per point is: $T_s = 15\ \rm msec$

My scan time for this measurement would be:

$$t_1 = n T_s = 6000 \cdot 15\ \rm msec = 90\ \rm sec$$

1. If I exceed the number of points in the required span by 2, can I decrease my required dwell time by 2?

$$t_2 = 90\ \rm sec = 12,000 \cdot 7.5\ \rm msec$$

2. Can these 2 measurements on a Spectrum Analyzer be considered "equivalent"?
3. What are the trade-offs?

To give some background, I am using a software tool that fixes the number of points in a span to default value. Since I cannot set number of points to exactly what is required, I would like to set the sweep times to the smallest allowed time. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for editing my question.  Do you have any idea why my question is not answered? Is this the wrong forum?

Comment: Answers are given for free. So, if someone is online and finds your question interesting to answer, they will provide the answer if they have that answer (and of course if they have the time for it). But in the meantime if you think some more details will be useful to the question, please edit your question accordingly and add that, it will give more visibility to your question.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your input.  This question is probably not hard to answer, just not very interesting.